# Calculate the specific time intervals between two given date values in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Given the following DataFrame of pandas in Python:

Displays the switching on and off of 3 bulbs at different times. Using datetime objects.

```
                        date          code     other              time
1  2022-02-27 15:30:21+00:00             5        ON               NaT
2  2022-02-29 17:05:21+00:00             5       OFF   2 days 01:35:00
3  2022-04-07 17:05:21+00:00             5       OFF               NaT
4  2022-04-06 16:10:21+00:00             4        ON               NaT
5  2022-04-07 15:30:21+00:00             4       OFF   0 days 23:20:00
6  2022-02-03 22:40:21+00:00             3        ON               NaT
7  2022-02-03 23:20:21+00:00             3       OFF   0 days 00:40:00
8  2022-02-04 00:20:21+00:00             3        ON               NaT
9  2022-02-04 14:30:21+00:00             3        ON               NaT
10 2022-01-31 15:30:21+00:00             3        ON               NaT
11 2022-02-04 15:35:21+00:00             3       OFF   4 days 00:05:00
12 2022-02-04 15:40:21+00:00             3       OFF               NaT
13 2022-02-04 19:40:21+00:00             3        ON               NaT
14 2022-02-06 15:35:21+00:00             3       OFF   1 days 19:55:00
15 2022-02-23 21:10:21+00:00             3        ON               NaT
16 2022-02-24 07:10:21+00:00             3       OFF   0 days 10:00:00
```

I want to add a new column, called `nights`. This column will include only for rows where the variable `time` is different from `NaT`. Information on how many nights the light bulb has been on. The night period is defined as 22:00:00 to 05:00:00.

Example of the resulting DataFrame:

```
                        date          code     other              time    nights
1  2022-02-27 15:30:21+00:00             5        ON               NaT      0
2  2022-02-29 17:05:21+00:00             5       OFF   2 days 01:35:00      2
3  2022-04-07 17:05:21+00:00             5       OFF               NaT      0
4  2022-04-06 16:10:21+00:00             4        ON               NaT      0
5  2022-04-07 15:30:21+00:00             4       OFF   0 days 23:20:00      1
6  2022-02-03 22:40:21+00:00             3        ON               NaT      0
7  2022-02-03 23:20:21+00:00             3       OFF   0 days 00:40:00      0
8  2022-02-04 00:20:21+00:00             3        ON               NaT      0
9  2022-02-04 14:30:21+00:00             3        ON               NaT      0
10 2022-01-31 15:30:21+00:00             3        ON               NaT      0
11 2022-02-04 15:35:21+00:00             3       OFF   4 days 00:05:00      4
12 2022-02-04 15:40:21+00:00             3       OFF               NaT      0
13 2022-02-04 19:40:21+00:00             3        ON               NaT      0
14 2022-02-06 15:35:21+00:00             3       OFF   1 days 19:55:00      2
15 2022-02-23 21:10:21+00:00             3        ON               NaT      0
16 2022-02-24 07:10:21+00:00             3       OFF   0 days 10:00:00      1
```

The light bulb ON register is just before the non-NaT value of the `time` variable.

**Information added**: In case the bulb is switched off and on in the middle of the night, it will not be taken into account for the variable `nights`. It has to spend the entire interval switched on.

```
                        date      code     other              time    nights
1  2022-02-27 21:00:00+00:00         1        ON               NaT      0
2  2022-02-28 01:00:00+00:00         1       OFF   0 days 04:00:00      0
3  2022-02-28 03:15:00+00:00         1        ON               NaT      0
4  2022-02-28 09:30:00+00:00         1       OFF   0 days 06:15:00      0
```

Comment: Does the lightbulb have to be on for the entire night in order for it to count?

Comment: @JordanHyatt Yes. For the ```night``` counter to increment by 1, the entire period from 22:00 to 05:00 of a day has to be in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing how you want to handle partial nights you could try something like this.... [Updated to handle partial days better] [Update to add imports]

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df['edate'] = df.date + df.time
df['first_night_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date.dt.date) + dt.timedelta(hours=22)
df['first_night_end'] = df['first_night_start'] + dt.timedelta(hours=7)
def get_nights(ser):
    if pd.isna(ser.time):
        return
    days = ser.time.days
    the_rest = ser.time - dt.timedelta(days)
    if ((ser.date + the_rest) > ser.first_night_end) and (ser.date < ser.first_night_start):
        return days + 1
    else:
        return days 
df['nights'] = df.apply(get_nights, axis=1)
```

Comment: I have added additional information for the case you mentioned, if you don't mind, take a look at it.

Comment: I think what I have should do it.  With my solution two partial nights would result in a night value of 1.  i.e. bulb goes on at 23:00 and is on for 24 hours returns 1 even though it was on partially in night 1 and partially in night 2.

Comment: Your code returns the following error (SOLVED): ```df['first_night_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date.dt.date) + dt.timedelta(hours=22)```

NameError: name 'dt' is not defined

Comment: import datetime as dt

Comment: And one more error in the ```get_nights``` function: ```AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'time'```

Comment: "time" was the name of one of your columns in your original dataframe....is it still present?  Is it capitalized?  Also make sure you pass axis=1 into apply

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245393/discussion-between-jordan-hyatt-and-carola).

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a datetime function. Solved, thank you very much!